# Problemas con la funcion Merge para actualizar o insertar, ejecutada desde C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

tengo un problema al querer migrar unos 30,000 registro de Excel a una tabla de SQL, lo estoy realizando desde C# y un procedimiento almacenado que ejecuta la función `merge` de SQL. Aquí el código.

Aquí paso un `datatable` al procedimiento almacenado

```
public ActionResult MigraCatalogo(int? Cat)
{
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
    var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    try
    {                            
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP-MtoCatArticulo-MigraCatalgo", connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tblMatCatAtriculo", dt);                           

        connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

...y el procedimiento que se ejecuta es el siguiente.

```
 USE [WebDBT]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP-MtoCatArticulo-MigraCatalgo]
@tblMatCatAtriculo MtoCatArticulo READONLY
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

MERGE MtoCatArticulo with (holdlock) AS Destino
USING
 (Select ClaveCucop,Gpo,GEn,Esp,Dif,[Var],CuadroBasico,Descripcion,Uni,Cant,Tipo,PartidaPresupuesta,Comentarios from @tblMatCatAtriculo) as Origen
 ON (ltrim(rtrim(Origen.Gpo))=ltrim(rtrim(Destino.Gpo))
  and ltrim(rtrim(Origen.Gen))=ltrim(rtrim(Destino.Gen))
  and ltrim(rtrim(Origen.Esp))=ltrim(rtrim(Destino.Esp))
  and ltrim(rtrim(Origen.Dif))=ltrim(rtrim(Destino.Dif))
  and ltrim(rtrim(Origen.[Var]))=ltrim(rtrim(Destino.[Var])))

  --Cuandos los registros concuerdan 

    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE

     SET Destino.ClaveCucop = Origen.ClaveCucop,
        Destino.CuadroBasico = Origen.CuadroBasico,
        Destino.Descripcion = Origen.Descripcion,
        Destino.Uni = Origen.Uni,
        Destino.Cant = Origen.Cant,
        Destino.Tipo = Origen.Tipo,
        Destino.PartidaPresupuesta = Origen.PartidaPresupuesta,
        Destino.Comentarios = Origen.Comentarios

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
       VALUES(
       Origen.ClaveCucop,
       Origen.Gpo,
       Origen.Gen,
       Origen.Esp,
       Origen.Dif,
       Origen.Var,
       Origen.CuadroBasico,
       Origen.Descripcion,
       Origen.Uni,
       Origen.Cant,
       Origen.Tipo,
       Origen.PartidaPresupuesta,
       Origen.Comentarios);       
END
```

Bien, la migración en sí no tiene ningún problema, la ejecuta correctamente. Sin embargo, tengo problemas cuando migro el mismo archivo con 30,000 registros y algunos de ellos llevan cambios en algunos campos, bueno pues los cambios no los realiza.

¿Podrían echarme una mano para ver que estoy haciendo mal?
Les comento que el Excel no trae un campo de tipo `id`, es por ello que los relaciono por los campo `Gpo`, `Gen`, `Esp`, `dif`, `Var`, que son los que menos cambios pueden tener.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: listo amigos con la propuesta de jav Fer2, pude solucionarlo

Comment: Por favor, no publiques una respuesta diciendo "gracias". En su lugar, **[acepta la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** que consideres como la mejor solución a tu problema. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/211979)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A priori tal y como lo estás comentando, parece bastante posible, que si se estén ejecutando los cambios, pero que unos cambios de la sentencia merge esté pisando a otros cambios. Si los registros a realizar el merge no tienen un campo que los relacione como únicos, solo quedará la última sentencia de modificación.

Por ejemplo si dos lineas de excel tienen valores que modifican la columna PartidaPresupuesta pero su identificacion Gpo, Gen, Esp, Dif, Var es la misma, se realizarán los dos cambios, pero solo verás uno.

La solución, para corroborar lo que te cuento, es utilizar OUTPUT, de la propia sentencia. Almacenarlo en una variable de tabla y darle salida. De este modo, sabes lo que ha realizado la sentencia.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP-MtoCatArticulo-MigraCatalgo]
(@tblMatCatAtriculo MtoCatArticulo READONLY)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
Declare @table table (
 ACCION NVARCHAR(100), 
 Gpo varchar(100),
 Gen varchar(100),
 Esp varchar(100),
 dif varchar(100),
 Var varchar(100),
 MyId INT IDENTITY(1,1)
);

MERGE MtoCatArticulo with (holdlock) AS Destino
USING
 (Select ClaveCucop,Gpo,GEn,Esp,Dif,[Var],CuadroBasico,Descripcion,Uni,Cant,Tipo,PartidaPresupuesta,Comentarios from @tblMatCatAtriculo) as Origen
 ON (ltrim(rtrim(Origen.Gpo))=ltrim(rtrim(Destino.Gpo))
  and ltrim(rtrim(Origen.Gen))=ltrim(rtrim(Destino.Gen))
  and ltrim(rtrim(Origen.Esp))=ltrim(rtrim(Destino.Esp))
  and ltrim(rtrim(Origen.Dif))=ltrim(rtrim(Destino.Dif))
  and ltrim(rtrim(Origen.[Var]))=ltrim(rtrim(Destino.[Var])))

  --Cuandos los registros concuerdan 

    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE

     SET Destino.ClaveCucop = Origen.ClaveCucop,
        Destino.CuadroBasico = Origen.CuadroBasico,
        Destino.Descripcion = Origen.Descripcion,
        Destino.Uni = Origen.Uni,
        Destino.Cant = Origen.Cant,
        Destino.Tipo = Origen.Tipo,
        Destino.PartidaPresupuesta = Origen.PartidaPresupuesta,
        Destino.Comentarios = Origen.Comentarios

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
       VALUES(
       Origen.ClaveCucop,
       Origen.Gpo,
       Origen.Gen,
       Origen.Esp,
       Origen.Dif,
       Origen.Var,
       Origen.CuadroBasico,
       Origen.Descripcion,
       Origen.Uni,
       Origen.Cant,
       Origen.Tipo,
       Origen.PartidaPresupuesta,
       Origen.Comentarios)
    OUTPUT $ACTION as MergeAction,
    inserted.gpo, inserted.gen, inserted.esp, inserted.dif, inserted.var;

    Select * from @table
END
```

Los únicos cambios al procedure, son la declaración de la variable de tabla, y la inclusión de la claúsula OUTPUT de la sentencia.

He puesto los datos, como varchar en la definición de la varialble de tabla, pero no se si se corresponden con la realidad.

[Merge](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/04/merge-upsert-insertar-o-actualizar-en-una-sola-sentencia/)